# iPhone localization not working properly

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization

I've been developing an app which is localized in two languages. Everything has been going good so far until today.

What happens is that if i deploy the application on device, it alternates between being localized and not being localized (in which case it just shows the localized keys and not strings). It is getting really really annoying and I haven't been able to find a solution for this. I think it has to do with my Xcode setup perhaps?

This happened earlier in another project as well, but I could never see what was the matter.

---

Well, right after posting this question, it struck me that the only common thing I added in both projects was the ShareKit. share kit introduces its own localizable strings and for some odd reason, the iOS alternates between ShareKit's localizable files and my own. Moving share kit localizations into my own fixed the issue.

How should such a situation be handled?

I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

> How should such a situation be handled?

The library (in this case, ShareKit) is at fault. Libraries that are meant to be included in other code should not use the default file name `Localizable.string`. They should give their `.strings` file a unique name and use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()` in their code.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should inform them.